# Short web comic of robot carrying a dead woman who helped him

Tags: story-identification, webcomics, androids, apocalypse

The web comic went something like: The world is ending, and this girl runs into a guy in the street who isn't aware and tells him to get to shelter with her. They stay together in the shelter during the bombings. Later she sees a bunch of kids beating up an android in the street and runs them off. She tells the boy that her father told her to treat androids with respect. The boy is being hinted at being an android. The comic then shows the boy with missing skin showing his robotic limbs, carrying the girl in the outskirts of the city, the acid rain starts to fall and he props her up against a cactus. He then covers her with himself as the acid rain just damages his fake skin. There's a line somewhere in the comic like "You can tell it's over when there's only one bomber".

I saw the comic on one of those sad post tumbler blogs, if that helps. This comic brings me a lot of emotion and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

I've been looking for it and have found it; it's called [*Don't Let Go*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGAQr.jpg) by Strangely Katie. I just read it again and I am crying a lot right now.

The robot carrying the woman can be seen in the below image:

[image: Don't Let Go page showing the robot carrying the woman]

I was trying to see if I could read it again on her page but for some reason the domain wasn't available.

Comment: I have edited to clear this up a bit to be a bit clearer. I also added in a page that I believe is one of the main ones the OP was referencing. If you disagree with any of my edits you can [edit] yourself to fix the post up.